# Java access static nested class

Tags: java, inner-classes

How can i create a instance of the following Class and access its methods.
Example:

```
public class A {
    public static class B {
        public static class C {
            public static class D {
                public static class E {
                    public void methodA() {}
                    public void methodB(){}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `A.B.C.D.E e = new A.B.C.D.E();` not sure what "How" means.

Comment: *FYI:* A class declared inside another class is called a *nested* class. If it is non-static, it is also called an *inner* class. Since your classes are `static`, they are generally called *static nested classes*. They are definitely not *inner* classes. JLS [§8.1.3. Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3): *An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly declared `static`.*

Comment: OP, have you looked this up in the Java documentation? The JLS answers this question. FYI, the documentation for things, like, oh, the Java language for example, is very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :

```
A.B.C.D.E e = new A.B.C.D.E();//create an instance of class E
e.methodA();//call methodA 
e.methodB();//call methodB
```

Or like @Andreas mention in comment you can use `import A.B.C.D.E;`, so if your class is in another packager then you can call your class using `name_of_package.A.B.C.D.E` like this:

```
import com.test.A.B.C.D.E;
//     ^^^^^^^^------------------------name of package

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        E e = new E();
        e.methodA();
        e.methodB();
    }
}
```

Comment: or `import A.B.C.D.E; E e = new E();`. And you need to qualify first `E` too, without the import. --- And for completeness, you might mention how it works if `A` is in a package.

Comment: yes @Andreas this is also can solve the problem check my edit

Comment: `Arrsyss`? If that was supposed to be example for package, then it should be lowercase, and a better example might be `org.example`.

Comment: no no @Andreas my mistake check now